# 'I'm about something' means

Tags: phrase-meaning

I watched the video [3.35 - 3.45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWxNPJFfhks) and they talked about, who should pay bill in date ? She said I'm broke if boy work somewhere he can pay **I'm about equality**. they explain that **'believe in something'** but I dont understand. Why she said I'm broke after said We are equality. Is that any different means ?

Comment: to pay the bill ***on a date***.

Answer (score 1):

She's just basically saying she's a **student** and **broke**, which is one of the biggest problems in life. A student has time but no money, but once you have a job, you have money but no time.

She says she believes in equality, but she's broke (as a student), so either she should date other students and starve (haha) or get a job and pay her own way.

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't focus all conversation, I considered only sentence but I understand trough your answer.